# How can I give a global callback function a local instance?

Tags: c++, callback, namespaces, glfw

In **global namespace** I have a GLFW callback function:

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        
    }
}
```

This function must recieve an object from **local namespace** of main function:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    Sphere lightSphere{ 0.8f, outerColor, centerColor };
    ...
}
```

And in main loop I have a GLFW callback function.

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
```

Is it possible to implement it without declaring an object in global namespace?

Comment: I don't know GLFW that well,but doesn't it have the concept or *user data*? If you can set a user-data pointer to a specific object, and retrieve that pointer inside the callback, then you could use that.

Comment: Unrelated: Do you really have to call `glfwSetKeyCallback` in a loop? I would expect it to be enough to call it once.

Comment: Thank you, I searched and there really are pointers for user data.

Comment: Thanks to Some programmer dude. I found the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the user pointer to `window` and retrieve it in the callback.

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &lightSphere);
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
```

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    Sphere* sphere = static_cast<Sphere*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
}
```